# Como importar várias abas do excel ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: r

Estou tentando reproduzir o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso. O que devo colocar no argumento `path`? É a mesma coisa em todos eles? Algum exemplo mais claro para que eu possa entender? Alguma dica de como importar várias "*sheets*" do excel ao mesmo tempo?

```
# To load all sheets in a workbook:

path <- readxl_example("datasets.xls")
lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)

###
In: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primeira coisa a ser feita é instalar o pacote `readxl`, através do comando

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Este passo só precisa ser feito uma vez. Com o pacote `readxl` instalado, é necessário carregá-lo na memória através do comando

```
library(readxl)
```

Este passo precisa ser feito toda vez que o R (ou RStudio) for fechado e depois reaberto.

O argumento `path` é o caminho para o arquivo .xls no teu computador. Por exemplo, ao rodar `path <- readxl_example("datasets.xls")` no meu PC, o resultado obtido é

```
path
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/readxl/
  extdata/datasets.xls"
```

Provavelmente o resultado no teu computador vai ser diferente, mas perceba que, ao final, ele também vai ter `.xls`, pois este é o endereço do arquivo de exemplos de conjuntos de dados do `readxl`. Para ler todas as planilhas de um arquivo .xls, rode os comandos

```
planilhas <- lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)
length(planilhas)
```

A primeira linha vai ler todas as planilhas dentro de um arquivo .xls e salvá-las dentro de um objeto chamado `planilhas`. O segundo comando vai te dizer quantas planilhas haviam neste arquivo. Agora basta rodar

```
planilhas[2]
```

por exemplo, para ver quais são os dados presentes na planilha 2 do arquivo .xls lido.

---

*Edição após [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262433/como-importar-v%c3%a1rias-abas-do-excel-ao-mesmo-tempo#comment538941_262486):*

É possível criar um data frame diferente para cada elemento da lista `planilhas` através do comando

```
for (j in 1:length(planilhas)){
  assign(paste("planilha", j, sep=""), planilhas[[j]])
}
```

Comment: Marcos, muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obtive uma "Large List" com 11 elementos. Para converter cada um desses elementos em data.frame eu poderia usar algo como: planilha4 <- planilhas[[4]]? Faria isso para cada elemento.

Comment: Sim. Veja a edição da resposta. Inclusive, se minha resposta te ajudou, [considere votar nela e aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Comment: Grato, a criação dos data.frames também funcionou pelo comando que você editou.